# Is there a way to point to a certain section of a string in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I would like to point to a certain part of a character array, i.e:

```
char string[] = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
char * pointer = points to the 'fox' part of string;
```

Is this possible to do without using strncpy or something similar?

Comment: like string +17 ?

Comment: `pointer = &string[17];`

Comment: Also: `pointer = strstr(string, "fox");` - this will scan `string` for the first occurrence of the phrase `"fox"` and returns a pointer to it.

Comment: Those would be `fox jumps over the lazy dog`, not `fox`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - correct.

Comment: So to extract fox I would need to have an temporary variable and copy that certain section of the string into it. I tested strncpy(pointer,string + 16,4); and that seems to work. I edited "pointer" to char pointer[4];

Comment: @raging-loon Twice you have mentioned `strncpy()` rather than say `strcpy()`.  `strncpy()` is easy to use improperly as is `strcpy()` as you just did with `strncpy(pointer,string + 16,4);`.  Your code copied `"fox "` and no _null character_. 
 `strncpy()`  rarely make for better code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I actually a way to do what I was really trying to do with strncmp. I needed to compare certain parts of a buffer to a map of opcodes. So I used strncmp(buffer + offset, opcode, length of opcode); if matched offset += length of opcode.

Comment: @raging-loon _Sounds good_, yet best to see compliable code rather than a description of code.  Good luck.

Comment: Check my answer (with code) to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73256866/17592432 It searches out keywords, which seems to be your objective... You won't want to change the case, but you may find value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without copying or modifying the string, you can only point to substrings with the same end (e.g., `fox jumps over the lazy dog`, `dog`, or `lazy dog`), not ones that end in the middle of the original string like `fox` or `lazy`.

Answer (score 3):

`strstr()` or similar user code can be used to find a sub-string within a *string*.

```
const char *haystack = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
const char *target = "fox";

char *needle = strstr(haystack, target);
```

To *print* a portion of the string like `"fox"`, use a *precision*.

```
if (needle == NULL) {
  printf("<%s> not found.\n");
} else {
  ptrdiff_t offset = needle - haystack;
  int precision = (int) strlen(target);
  printf("<%.*s> found at offset %td.\n", precision, needle, offset);
}
```

Comment: Beware that `strstr` silently discards the `const` pointer, so when afterwards you want to perform an operation on `needle`, this might cause issues if `haystack` is a string literal. This example will be fine, but be careful if you are attempting to modify string literals.